# Amazon SES not working is not working with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-ses

I have created an email address and verified it under SES > Email Address. And then i have created a SMTP user, but when i am integrating it with codeigniter it is showing me timeout error.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
$ci = get_instance();
$ci->load->library('email');
$config = array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'MY HOST',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'newline' => '\r\n',
    'smtp_user' => 'AWS SMTP USER',
    'smtp_pass' => 'AWS SMTP PASSWORD',
    'mailtype' => 'html',
    'charset' => 'utf-8'
);
$this->email->initialize($config);
$ci->email->from('abc@example.com', 'Example');
$ci->email->to('someone@example.com');
$ci->email->subject('Testing');
$ci->email->message('This is testing');

if (!$ci->email->send()) {
    show_error($ci->email->print_debugger());
}
```

Comment: Not a true answer, but you should use PHPMailer. I love CodeIgniter, but I wouldn't trust anything but PHPMailer to easily and correctly handle my mail.

Answer (score 0):

Change line:

```
'newline' => '\r\n',
```

To:

```
'newline' => "\r\n",
```

Also I would add host as:

```
'smtp_host' => 'ssl://MY HOST',
```